# Differences GMapping ROS/ROS 2

Tags: ros, navigation, ros2, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is gmapping in ROS 2 better than in ROS?
Right now i'm using a Turtlebot3 that has the best support for ROS kinetic. But i find the Gmapping that comes out of the box pretty lackluster (Being outperformed by hector).
Does ROS 2 actually have better Gmapping than ROS Kinetic?

Thanks in advance :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/344898/differences-gmapping-ros/ros-2/) by [kopop8](https://answers.ros.org/users/52035/kopop8/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2020-02-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No.

In fact, there is no supported branch of slam gmapping, nor will there likely to be. The default recommended option for ROS2 is [SLAM Toolbox](https://github.com/SteveMacenski/slam_toolbox).

The distribution of ROS doesn't change the underlying algorithm, its just the piping. I wouldn't expect now or any time in the future for any serious development on gmapping.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kopop8](https://answers.ros.org/users/52035/kopop8/) on 2020-02-25**:
Thanks a lot :)